# Compare two hashmaps and remove duplicates from second hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

```
HashMap<Double, Date> hm1 = new HashMap<Double, Date>();
HashMap<Double, Date> hm2 = new HashMap<Double, Date>();

hm1.put(11, Wed Feb 23 12:56:24 IST 2022);
hm1.put(12, Wed Feb 23 12:56:48 IST 2022);
hm1.put(13, Wed Feb 23 12:56:45 IST 2022);
hm1.put(14, Wed Feb 23 12:56:51 IST 2022);
hm1.put(15, Wed Feb 23 12:56:50 IST 2022);

hm2.put(11, Wed Feb 23 12:56:24 IST 2022);
hm2.put(12, Wed Feb 23 12:56:48 IST 2022);
hm2.put(13, Wed Feb 23 12:56:45 IST 2022);
hm2.put(17, Wed Feb 23 12:56:37 IST 2022);
hm2.put(18, Wed Feb 23 12:56:28 IST 2022);
```

Need to compare these two hashmaps and get output as hashmap which contains the filtered entries from hm2 i.e remove duplicates after comparing with hm1

output should be

```
hm2 = {17=Wed Feb 23 12:56:37 IST 2022,
18=Wed Feb 23 12:56:28 IST 2022}
```

Comment: by duplicate , you mean both key and value are same or even if key matches, then remove

Comment: There are no duplicates in a Java `Map`. Are you looking for `Map.removeAll()`?

Comment: @GurkiratSinghGuliani only when both the key and the value of an entry in hm2 matches with any of the entries in hm1 it should be removed from hm2

Comment: @user207421 No am not looking for removeAll() besides could you be a little more elaborate in explaining your answer ? hope you got the question right.

Answer (score 2):

Use the remove method which accepts two params (key and value).

> Removes the entry for the specified key only if it is currently mapped
> to the specified value.

So in your case:

```
hm1.forEach((k,v) -> hm2.remove(k,v));
```

Comment: I guess you will agree that mutation of objects outside the lambda isn't considered to be a good practice. You might do the same inside the *enhanced for loop* over the entry set of the first map. The only difference is that `k` and `v` will turn to `entry.getKey()` and `entry.getValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

If key and value must be the same in order to qualify as a duplicate it would be something like:

```
    Map<Integer, String> hm1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    Map<Integer, String> hm2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    hm1.put(11, "Wed Feb 23 12:56:24 IST 2022");
    hm1.put(12, "Wed Feb 23 12:56:48 IST 2022");
    hm1.put(13, "Wed Feb 23 12:56:45 IST 2022");
    hm1.put(14, "Wed Feb 23 12:56:51 IST 2022");
    hm1.put(15, "Wed Feb 23 12:56:50 IST 2022");

    hm2.put(11, "Wed Feb 23 12:56:24 IST 2022");
    hm2.put(12, "Wed Feb 23 12:56:48 IST 2022");
    hm2.put(13, "Wed Feb 23 12:56:45 IST 2022");
    hm2.put(17, "Wed Feb 23 12:56:37 IST 2022");
    hm2.put(18, "Wed Feb 23 12:56:28 IST 2022");

    //removing duplicates
    for (Integer key : hm1.keySet()) {
        if (hm2.containsKey(key)) {
            if (hm1.get(key).equals(hm2.get(key))) {
                hm2.remove(key);
            }
        }
    }
    
    // show content of hm2
    System.out.println(hm2);
    

}
```

If only the key is relevant to qualify as a duplicate use

```
for (Integer key : hm1.keySet()) {
     hm2.remove(key);           
}
```

instead of

```
for (Integer key : hm1.keySet()) {
        if (hm2.containsKey(key)) {
            if (hm1.get(key).equals(hm2.get(key))) {
                hm2.remove(key);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct you need to *remove from the second map all entries that are contained in the first map*. I.e. if both a key and its value are the same).

***Side note:** class `Date` is obsolete and not encouraged to be used. With **Java 8** a new IPA that resides in the package `java.time` was introduced for such purposes. So I replaced `Date` with `LocalDateTime`. If for some reason you can't make this change then simply substitute `LocalDateTime` with `Date`.*

The first step is to make a *defensive copy* of the second map. From your definition of the problem the second map itself has to be mutated, so if you don't need to preserve it intact you *omit this step*, but for *future readers*, it's worth being included in the code.

To address the problem *fluently* instead of nested conditions with `containsKey()` checks you can make use of **Java 8**  enhancements. The flavor of the `remove()` that takes a *key* and *value* is already mentioned in another answer so I'll sow the alternative approach with the [**compute()**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) method which was also added into the JDK with **Java 8**.

Method `compute()` takes two arguments: a *key* and *remappingFunction* which is a [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) that excepts as its arguments the *given key* and *existing value* associated with that key (it'll be `null` if the *key is absent*). If *remapping function* returns `null` entry will be removed (in case if it was present).

In the code below iteration happens over the *keys* in the first map (denoted with a parameter `vocub`). Method `compute()` is being applied to the `result` map, this *lambda expression*

```
(k, v) -> !Objects.equals(v, vocab.get(k)) ? v : null
```

has the **following meaning**:

- `k` - the given key;
- `v` - value from `result` map associated with that key;
- `Objects.equals(v, vocab.get(k))` does a *null-friendly* comparison of existing value (which could be `null`) and a value from the first map.

If both values are equal it *remaping function* yields `null`, i.e entry will be removed.

```
public static Map<Double, LocalDateTime> removeDuplicates(Map<Double, LocalDateTime> vocab,
                                                          Map<Double, LocalDateTime> target) {
    Map<Double, LocalDateTime> result = new HashMap<>(target);
    for (Double key: vocab.keySet()) {
        result.compute(key, (k, v) -> !Objects.equals(v, vocab.get(k)) ? v : null);
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you are comfortable with **Stream IPA** it could be done by iterating over the *entry set* of the second map and comparing values in both maps.

```
public static Map<Double, LocalDateTime> removeDuplicates(Map<Double, LocalDateTime> vocab,
                                                          Map<Double, LocalDateTime> target) {
    return target.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> !Objects.equals(entry.getValue(), vocab.get(entry.getKey())))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                      Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Double, LocalDateTime> map1 =
            Map.of(1., LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(3),
                    2., LocalDateTime.now().minusMonths(1),
                    3., LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(5)
                    8., LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(1)); // this key isn't present in the map2

    Map<Double, LocalDateTime> map2 =
            Map.of(1., LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(3),
                    2., LocalDateTime.now().minusMonths(1),
                    3., LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(5),
                    9., LocalDateTime.now());

    System.out.println(removeDuplicates(map1, map2));
}
```

**Output** (both versions)

```
{9.0=2022-02-23T17:56:27.784812600}
```